# Is muPdf able to read iranian (farsi) digits?

Tags: excel, mupdf, farsi

I have a PDF file containing Iranian/Farsi digits:
http://antiguide.free.fr/divers/20200220_pdf2excel/azar_1398.pdf

I wish convert it to Excel.
When I run mutool it seems that digits are "visualy" interpreted as latin characters, ie "seven" is translated as V, "eight" as A; "nine" as  '\ .

Is it a way to bypass conversion ?

Regards.
PO.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are exepcting as output, IIRC the output will be UTF-8 encoded. You'll need to read the text with somethign which can understand UTF-8 encoded Unicode text.